# both tow are unicode,but when compare,it doesn't work？

Tags: python, unicode

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup 
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://bbs.szhome.com/80300-0-0-0-3005.html')
html = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

returntext = soup.find('dl',class_='fix').text 
print returntext

if isinstance(returntext,unicode):
    print 'ok1' #true,print ok1

text = u'暂无相关数据...'

if isinstance(text,unicode):
    print 'ok2' #true,print ok2

text2 = '暂无相关数据...'
if isinstance(text2,str):
    print 'ok3' #true,print ok3

if returntext == text:
    print 'ok4' #both unicode,but not excute,why?
```

Comment: I assume that the question is about your `text` and `text2` test... the url and beautifulsoup stuff don't really matter here, do they?

Comment: `print repr(text)` and `print repr(returntext)` and why they miscompare will be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) all newlines before comparison:

```
>>> print returntext

暂无相关数据...

>>> print text
暂无相关数据...
>>> returntext
u'\n\u6682\u65e0\u76f8\u5173\u6570\u636e...\n'
>>> text
u'\u6682\u65e0\u76f8\u5173\u6570\u636e...'
>>> returntext.strip() == text
True
```

Comment: Um, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with OP's problem. Where did `returntext` come from and why aren't you comparing it with the text2 string?

Comment: @tdelaney Read the OP's code. He is fetching returntext from a webpage. He is also not comparing text2 with text anywhere.

Comment: @tdelaney He might have been comparing text with returntext and text2 with returntext to see which one matches, and both have failed, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't both unicode, they just look that way to you because your display decodes text2 for you. In fact, `isinstance(text2,str)` shows that text2 is clearly a string, not unicode.

Unicode was bolted onto python 2 and its usage is a little strange. `str` can hold any octet (typically ascii characters but binary binary data) and in your case its holding a utf-8 encoded version of the string.

`text` is unicode and has 9 characters

```
>>> text = u'暂无相关数据...'
>>> type(text), len(text)
(<type 'unicode'>, 9)
```

`Text2` is a binary blob in a string, has 21 octets and is not the same as `text`

```
>>> text2 = '暂无相关数据...'
>>> type(text2), len(text2)
(<type 'str'>, 21)
>>> text == text2
__main__:1: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
False
```

But I can decode it into unicode and the comparison works

```
>>> text2_unicode = text2.decode('utf-8')
>>> type(text2_unicode), len(text2_unicode)
(<type 'unicode'>, 9)
>>> text == text2_unicode
True
```

This all works much better and much more clearly in python 3. You should not be using 2.x if you can avoid it.